# California Gubernatorial Election Turnouts

Tags: elections

I'm able to find the number of votes by a particular year on each election's Wikipedia page (such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_gubernatorial_election,_2010), but they all link back to a pdf on the state website (such as http://www.sos.ca.gov/elections/sov/2010-general/complete-sov.pdf).

Have there been any attempts to aggregate this data in tabular format? I see http://openelections.net/results/#ca but it is not populated yet.

The reason I care is because I have recently found out that the gubernatorial turnout is directly related to the amount of signatures necessary to put a California proposition onto the ballot, so would like to compare the rates of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resource has a more direct reference to what I want: http://ballotpedia.org/Signature_requirements_for_ballot_measures_in_California. It seems to circumvent the data quality issues (or at least -- the interpretability issue) of the nationbuilder data too.

Answer (score 2):

I found this excellent resource: https://elections.nationbuilder.com/ca

And here is the data dictionary: https://elections.nationbuilder.com/about/data_columns

Registration may be required.